# Extract text element separated by hash & comma and store it in separate variable

Tags: python

I have text file having this content

```
group11#,['631', '1051']#,ADD/H/U_LS_FR_U#,group12#,['1', '1501']#,ADD/H/U_LS_FR_U#,group13#,['31', '28']#,ADD/H/UC_DT_SS#,group14#,['18', '27', '1017', '1073']#,AN/H/UC_HR_BAN#,group15#,['13']#,AD/H/U_LI_NW#,group16#,['1031']#,AN/HE/U_LE_NW_IES#
```

Requirment is to pull each element separated by **#,** and to store it in separate variable. And text file above is not having fixed length. So if there are 200 #, separated values then, those should be stored in 200 varaiables.
So the expected output would be

```
a = group11, b = [631, 1051] c = ADD/H/U_LS_FR_U, d = group12, e = [1, 1501] f = ADD/H/U_LS_FR_U and so on
```

I'd use those a,b,c,d further as

```
url = (url+c)
rjson = {"reqparam":{"ids":[str(b)]+str(b)}]}
freq = json.dumps(rjson)
resp = request.request("Post",url,rjson)
```

Actually in reqparam 'b' have to use values like 631 and 1051
Not sure how to achieve this?
I've started with

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    value = line.strip().split('#')
print(value)
```

Comment: `a = group11` what is *group11*?

Comment: data.split("#")?

Comment: All the values in `a,b,c,d etc ` should be strings. How do you want to store 2 values `631, 1051` in one variable `b` ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght group11 is just a string

Comment: PS. you might want to put `value = []`  before your for loop  and `value.append(line.strip().split('#`))` to it so you do not overwrite it all the time

Comment: @PatrickArtner How to store them individually in variables. I am not sure how to dynamically create variables to store those extracted values. I'd be using them as input later on

Comment: @AmRey why do you want to create 200 variables ? You can just store it in a list and then use it when and how required. Its not advisable to create variables in loop.

Comment: To use them as input later, just find out the length of the list and then access it using index.

Comment: Adding the result of `line.split('#,')` to an existing array will result in the array being filled with seperate entries. You can then iterate over them to get every value induvidually. Is this what you want ?

Comment: For your deleted question, I think https://regex101.com/r/p2YOoc/1 will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for quick help ... was able to extract text earlier so deleted the question

Answer (score 0):

You should not use new variable for each object, there are different containers for this, e.g. [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

To parse this string into a list, you can just split string using `"#,"` as a divider and cut last symbol (which is `"#"`) from source before strip:

```
result = src[:-1].split(",#")
```

But in output sample you show that you want items which contains list to be converted into a list. You can do this using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
result = [ast.literal_eval(s) if "[" in s else s for s in src[:-1].split("#,")]
```

I used [list comprehesion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in previous example, but you can write it using regular `for` loop:

```
import ast    

result = []
for s in src[:-1].split(",#"):
    if "[" in s:
        try:
            converted = ast.literal_eval(s) # string repr of list into a list
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\"{s}\" throws an error: {e}")
        else:
            result.append(converted) 
    else:
        result.append(s)
```

You can also use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to cut `"#"` and `","` from the end of the string (and from the start):

```
src.strip(",#").split(",#")
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght I am doing this `with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    value = line.strip("#,").split('#,')


mystr =  ','.join(map(str,value)) 

result = []
for s in mystr[:-1].split("#,"):
    if "[" in s:
        result.append(ast.literal_eval(s)) 
    else:
        result.append(s)`  and getting error this error **ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000278291A8CA0>**

Comment: @AmRey, in you code you firstly split string into a list (`value = line.strip("#,").split('#,')`), after that you join it back into a string (`mystr = ','.join(map(str,value))`) and at the end you're trying to split this string again (`mystr[:-1].split("#,")`). Firstly, it's useless and you can delete first two actions. Also your string after this manipulations can't be splited using same separator.

Comment: Oops.. yes, I commented that part earlier

Comment: @Amrey, this error still appears? I have patched code in my answer to show you which line throws an error.

Comment: `with open("extractedMCU.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines() mystr = str(data) result = []
for s in data[:-1].split():
    if "[" in s:
        try:
            converted = ast.literal_eval(s) # string repr of list into a list
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\"{s}\" throws an error: {e}")
        else:
            result.append(converted)
    else:
        result.append(s)` now I am getting the partial output with logger **throws an error: unmatched ']' (<unknown>, line 1)**

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght I am getting all the strings like **,ADD/H/U_LS_FR_U#,group12#** .. observed this error for second item in **[]** like `['1034'," throws an error: unmatched ']' (<unknown>, line 1)
"'2023']#`

Comment: @AmRey, there was a typo in answer, pretty obvious, probably you haven't fixed it. I have edited answer.